# NSClassFromString works for string literals, returns nil for constructed strings

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create an instance of a type based on another type passed into a method. I find that `NSClassFromString` works just fine if used with a string literal, as in

```
id instance = [[NSClassFromString(@"TheNameOfTheClassIWant") alloc] init];
```

but if I construct the string with something like

```
NSString *inClassName = [[protoInstance class] description];
NSString *outClassName = [inClassName stringByAppendingFormat:@"IWant"];
id instance = [[NSClassFromString(outClassName) alloc] init];
```

that `instance` is `nil`. Does `NSClassFromString` only work with literals? Is something happening at compile time to make `NSClassFromString` work?

Comment: Have you checked out the value of outClassName ?

Comment: I verified the strings were equal by eyeballing them. I just went back to compare them in code, and found that I was using the wrong string literal. When I use the right string literal, that fails as well. The class does exist, and I can create instances of it without NSClassFromString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've never had a problem using this call (granted, i have only needed it a few times).

you've:

- verified that `outClassName` is letter perfect (case-sensitive)?
- verified that the bundle/class has loaded? you are able to alloc/init a class using the standard approach?
- verified the output of `NSClassFromString' - just to ensure that`init` isn't returning 0 (as one example)

Comment: More information. If I create an instance of the class in the normal way, then subsequent calls to NSClassFromString work. Otherwise, NSClassFromString itself is returning nil. Do I really have to create an instance of each class in my project before being able to use NSClassFromString?

Comment: It must be enough to call the initializer. Do something like [myClassName class] to "register" the class without building an instance

Comment: @Jim it's possible. you can set a breakpoint `+[SOMEClass load` or `+[SOMEClass initialize]` to test whether the class has loaded into the runtime by the time you call `NSClassFromString`. see also `objc_getClass` and `objc_allocateClassPair` (the latter if you're creating classes at runtime)

Comment: @Gobra That works! Thank you. I'll just hide that messy bit of business in a method that gets called at start up.

Comment: As long as it is spelled correctly, `NSClassFromString()` will always work, regardless of whether the class has ever been referenced before.  Given that the class is already in the runtime and can be directly instantiated, the name must be mispelled.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is [Class description] is dubious. Use NSStringFromClass to be sure you got what you want?

Comment: description seemed to have been working, but NSStringFromClass is a better technique, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the class is included in **Build Phase** of your target. I had the same issue - the class had been dropped out of the build phase due to an unrelated change.