# NSClassFromString with String coming from Plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, swift, plist

I'm trying to instanciate a class in Swift from a String, ok it can sound weird but the ClassName comes from a Plist.

I'm using NSClassFromString but it doesn't work with the Plist String, I think that I'm close to this question: 
[NSClassFromString works for string literals, returns nil for constructed strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892353/nsclassfromstring-works-for-string-literals-returns-nil-for-constructed-strings)

But I can't use the solution as I can't know the possible classname coming from the Plist

The weird behavior is that if I create the *String* manually in the code, with the same value then it works as expected... it's like the converted String from the Plist is not the real exact same thing as a new String.

There is the code

```
let className: String = definition["class"] as! String
let classNameManualy: String = "AppName.ServiceTest"
let aClass = NSClassFromString(className) as! NSObject.Type
let instanceObject = aClass()
```

It works with *classNameManualy* but not with *className*

Then I put a breakpoint and I have identified a slighly difference

[image: DebugView]

Do you have a magic answer ?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried replacing `String` with `NSString`? How about building up `classNameManually` instead of using a literal string? BTW: how did `classNameManually` become `classNameManualy` in your screen shot?

Comment: What "slighly difference" are you talking about? `countAndFlags` will be different because a compile-rind string is in the code and can never be released and has a very different count.

Comment: @JefferyThomas: Yes I tried, yeah sorry there is an typo in the question I'll update it. ( it's ok in the code, I trippled check before to post ;) )

Comment: @zaph: I don't know that deep about, I've just seen this difference and I provided that to you. But ok if it's normal then why these 2 strings have a different result as an argument of NSClassFromString ?

Comment: @Plopix Can you post your `ServiceTest` class?